# Open existing or new activity from browser

Tags: android, android-intent, url-scheme

I am trying to implement an intent filter but for some reason (unknown to me) can succeed.

I declared activity in the following way:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.StartActivity"
    android:label="@string/start_activity_title"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
    android:exported="true">

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>

        <data
            android:scheme="myapp"
            android:host="terms-signed.com"
            android:pathPrefix="/?"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The browser tries to open URIs like `myapp://terms-signed.com/?documentKey=SOME-HEX`

No matter if I put such URI in the browser address field or if I tap on a similar link in a HTML page, nothing happens.

There is no chooser shown, my app does not become foremost, Android does not launch my app if it's not running. Nothing. Only browser shows page with message that the webpage at the address might be temporarily down etc.

I am using Android 4.2.1 / Galaxy Nexus.

What can be done to make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `?` from the pathPrefix, it is not a part of the path. Maybe you can even remove the whole pathPrefix parameter, as you don't have any path after the host.

Edit2: As it can be seen in the comments, additionally removing the hyphen and the .com from the host declaration resolved the issue. My best guess would be that the browser will treat the URI as a web URI because of the .com, regardless if it is using a custom scheme.

Comment: Unfortunately, it does not help. I tried to remove the `?` and `pathPrefix` - nothing changed.

Comment: Added some additional ideas into my answer, maybe they will help

Comment: Thank you, but this doesn't work either. I must be doing something terribly wrong.

Comment: How do you test this? With an actual web page and with the browser, or with a WebView? WebViews don't work the same way as a browser and won't open apps with such links if you don't tell them so. Entering the URI into the address bar of the browser also did not work for me. Only links on web pages did work.

Comment: I open page in default browser (not Google Chrome) in tap on the link.

Comment: Hmm... to narrow down the cause: have you tried to not specify the host, but only the scheme and looked if that works?

Comment: Well, then I'd guess that either the hyphen or the .com doesn't work correctly with this filters. Or maybe the combination of a custom scheme and the .com results in the browser treating the URI as a web URI..

Comment: Bingo! Removing hyphen and .com solved the issue. Thank you! You might  want to update your answer for future visitors.